# PowerMock: how to return null by default?

Tags: java, junit, powermock, easymock

I'm using PowerMock, EasyMock combo.

How do i make every mocked object return 'null' by default if not specified otherwise?

Now, i have to 'expect'(or 'when' in the mockito world) for every method of the mocked objects.

Comment: You should check out Mockito. I switched to using Mockito from EasyMock years ago because I battled the same thing. With Mockito, a mocked object returns null by default except for methods that return a Collection or a primitive. For Collections an empty collection is returned and primitives return their default values. Even if you don't convert your whole project to use Mockito, you could use it for this specific test.

Comment: @JoshChappelle It's the same with EasyMock, unless you used it wrong (ie, used `createMock` when it should have been `createNiceMock`).

Comment: Maybe it was the whole replay business that I couldn't stand. No need to replay in Mockito.

Comment: Thanks @Rogério ! Since you answered it first, could you post the same answer as an answer, i'll mark it as 'correct'

Comment: It's ok, you can accept @dur's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Rogério](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2326914/rog%c3%a9rio) commented, you can use [EasyMock#createNiceMock](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#createNiceMock-java.lang.Class-):

> Creates a mock object that implements the given interface, order checking is disabled by default, and the mock object will return 0, null or false for unexpected invocations.

or [EasyMock#niceMock](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#niceMock-java.lang.Class-):

> Creates a mock object that implements the given interface, order checking is disabled by default, and the mock object will return 0, null or false for unexpected invocations.